# Generating a cosine wave with multisim

Tags: operational-amplifier, waveform, multisim

I'm attempting to complete a project using multisim. I have to determine resistor and source values for a differential opamp.

One of the specifications is to supply a -10 amplitude cosine wave when t=5s.

I figured out how to generate a sine wave using the function generator, but I cant find a way to switch it to cosine.

Anyone know how to either make the function generator cosine, or produce a cosine source?

Comment: Trick question. For the purpose of simulation sine = cosine.

Comment: Here's an identity for you. \$\sin(x+\pi /2) = \cos(x)\$

Comment: MKUltra, do you believe the answer you got is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Cosine signal = sinusoidal signal, but +90 degrees phase shifted. The phase angle is one of the parameters of the sine voltage source Zero degrees=sine, +90 degrees=cosine.